# Can't load WSDL when creating SoapClient

Tags: php, soap

I have started getting the following error when I make a Soap call.

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://soapapi.findapprenticeship.service.gov.uk/Services/VacancyDetails/VacancyDetails51.svc?WSDL'
```

My code is...

```
$wsdl = 'https://soapapi.findapprenticeship.service.gov.uk/Services/VacancyDetails/VacancyDetails51.svc?WSDL'
$this->client = new SoapClient($wsdl, ['trace' => true]);


$this->client->__setSoapHeaders([
    new SoapHeader($this->namespace, 'PublicKey', env('PublicKey')),
    new SoapHeader($this->namespace, 'MessageId', Uuid::uuid4()->toString()),
    new SoapHeader($this->namespace, 'ExternalSystemId', env('ExternalSystemId')),
]);
```

I can browse to the url so I know it's there and working, it's just that the SoapClient can't. What's so weird is that it was working fine last week and but I noticed on 2 different Macs I use, that it has started throwing this error.

Can anyone help?

Thanks